# Check which controller and method is sending request on exception handling in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I want to get the controller and the method when handling the exception in Handler.

I don't want to use a try-catch on the controller.

Is there a way to achieve that? I was not able to find an example in the documentation.

```
$this->renderable(function (NotFoundHttpException $e, $request) {
            if ($request->is('api/*')) {
                //check here the controller and the method
                return responder()->error($e->getMessage())->respond(404);
            }
        });
```

Comment: In not into Laravel, but just for clarification: If you have an NotFound Exception at this point, witch controller and method are you looking for, when it seems that the current route does not exists?

Comment: @Foobar NotFoundHttpException is thrown when the model is not found. Route exists and it is coming from a controller and method which tries to find a model data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use these route methods:

> `$request->route()->getControllerClass();`

> `$request->route()->getActionMethod();`

You can check these and other Route methods here: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html

Comment: One more question, can I also get the $request->route("id") parameter in Handler?

Comment: Yes. With `$request->route()->parameters` or `$request->route()->parameter("id")`

Comment: I am getting "Call to a member function getActionMethod() on null" for some requests how can I handle it?

Comment: Can be a lot of things, we can't know without reading the code. One thing you can do is to verifify if $request->route() exists before trying to access its value.